# Block site clone

Tags: .htaccess

Some sites sometimes appear displaying exactly the same content as that of my site, when I edit something on my site, it is also automatically modified in these sites copies.

They are not iframes, I already added it to .htaccess:

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?meusite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^185\.162\.11\.243 #IP do Site Clone
RewriteRule ^ - [F]`

Comment: Those sites use a proxy to relay requests. No magic here, nothing much you can do. You _could_ try to examine the request headers if you can detect that proxy by some hint, but that will only work if the site operators worked in a sloppy way. In case they do _not_ use dynamic addresses you can also try to block their IP address, but they certainly will react to that.

Comment: The best in such case still is to talk to each other: directly address them.